# Is there a command for monitoring network connections in realtime on FreeBSD?

Tags: networking, monitoring, freebsd, network-monitoring, command

I'm having problems all over our LAN where Firefox is not closing network connections when using our internal webapp. It closes some but not all of the connections, repeat this often enough and your browser takes minutes to open a page.

I'm looking for a way to monitor the state of TCP connection that is a little more elegant than hitting netstat over and over. Something like tcpview from sysinternals but for bsd would be great.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use tcptrack. It will help in tracking open connections. It uses ncurses and can sort connections based on transfer rate.

Comment: This looks perfect, I'll give it a try. ntop nearly had it but I want to avoid a big application.

Answer (score 3):

In FreeBSD ports there are a lot of utilities to do just that.  You might try iftop or darkstat.  In the net-mgmt directory in the ports tree, tcptrack, iftop, darkstat, and ntop are all available.  There is a lot more there.

There is also [vnstat](http://humdi.net/vnstat/) but I didn't see a port in net-mgmt.

Comment: darkstat looks like a really useful tool, I just need a simple CL tool here but I can definitely think of other places for darkstat.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/). You start the process as a daemon, then connect using a web browser and you can watch real time throughput and statistics.

I'm not sure it can get the per-process connection state - but it's a big app with many options. Could be useful.

It does work on *BSD.

Comment: I had just found ntop, I' actually thinking the interactive state will let me sit at the computer, do an action, see the result. Hopefully I can see whats causing these connections to not close. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) if you want a GUI tool

Answer (score 1):

strange that nobody mentioned [pftop](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/pftop/), that can be used in pair with your [pf](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) firewall:

> Pftop is a small, curses-based utility
>   for real-time display of active states
>   and rule statistics for pf, the packet
>   filter (for OpenBSD)

Comment: [pftop](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pftop) is an excellent tool for viewing connections managed by the firewall. In some cases though, as in a gateway setup, the firewall is not involved and a different tool such as [tcptrack](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tcptrack) is needed.